# "I prefer to not do that" or "I prefer not to do that" or something else?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have no idea how to express myself correctly in this case. What is the right way to say that:

> "I prefer **to not do** that"

or

> "I **prefer not to** do that"

or

> something else?

Answer (score 2):

**i prefer not to** is grammatically correct, so is **i prefer to not**

The first is far more common. There is no difference whatsoever with the exception of:

**i prefer not to smoke**

**i prefer to not smoke...** that implies you want to make an emphasis on something you prefer

I suggest you see this answer https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23152/order-of-not-with-infinitive